# Intellij set keyboard scroll speed?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

Is there a way to set the keyboard scroll speed in `IntelliJ`? When I hold down the up and down arrows the movement is too slow for me and frustrates me when moving through a file.

Answer (score 14):

If you use Mac, go to the System Preferences application, click the Keyboard icon, the Keyboard tab and adjust the Repeat settings:

- Key Repeat determines how fast a caret moves.
- Delay Until Repeat determines how soon a caret starts moving after pressing a keyboard arrow.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **Windows** the program **Keyboard King** will allow you do this by overriding the operating systems limits for specific keys, the 'up' and 'down' keys in your case.

You can download it here http://bandwidthcontroller.com/Keyboard%20King/index.html

Comment: Thanks but on OSX sorry :/

Comment: The program **Karabiner** will do a similar thing for you in OSX. Install it, select the 3rd menu option **Key Repeat**, then just override the system's value and set your own. You can download it here: **[link](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)**. Credit to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10467/how-to-increase-keyboard-key-repeat-rate-on-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible natively, even in 2022. What @Finesse suggestd works, but only to a certain extent. I wanted to go even faster.

There's a plugin called "Jumper" though, that allows you to jump X lines using a predefined key-binding. I remapped the existing scroll buttons to use the "Jumper" actions and now I'm able to scroll (it's really moving the cursor) X lines at once.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux key repeat settings, see https://askubuntu.com/a/846035/456255.

> These settings are under Settings → Universal Access → Typing → Repeat Keys. You have to click the Repeat Keys row item, which brings up a pop-up dialog with two settings: Delay and Speed.